# How does fork system call really works

Tags: c, system-calls, fork

I've a very specific question about fork system call. I've this piece of code:

```
int main (void) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        pid_t pid = fork ();

        if ( !pid ) {
            printf("CHILD | PID: %d, PPID: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
            _exit(i + 1);
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int status;
        waitpid(-1, &status, 0);

        if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
            printf("IM %d AND CHILD WITH EXIT CODE %d TERMINATED\n",
                    getpid(), WEXITSTATUS(status));

        } 
        else {
            printf("ERROR: CHILD NOT EXITED\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

which produces this output:

```
CHILD | PID: 3565, PPID: 3564
CHILD | PID: 3566, PPID: 3564
IM 3564 AND CHILD WITH EXIT CODE 1 TERMINATED
IM 3564 AND CHILD WITH EXIT CODE 2 TERMINATED
CHILD | PID: 3573, PPID: 3564
CHILD | PID: 3567, PPID: 3564
IM 3564 AND CHILD WITH EXIT CODE 9 TERMINATED
IM 3564 AND CHILD WITH EXIT CODE 3 TERMINATED
CHILD | PID: 3568, PPID: 3564
IM 3564 AND CHILD WITH EXIT CODE 4 TERMINATED
CHILD | PID: 3569, PPID: 3564
IM 3564 AND CHILD WITH EXIT CODE 5 TERMINATED
CHILD | PID: 3570, PPID: 3564
IM 3564 AND CHILD WITH EXIT CODE 6 TERMINATED
CHILD | PID: 3571, PPID: 3564
IM 3564 AND CHILD WITH EXIT CODE 7 TERMINATED
CHILD | PID: 3572, PPID: 3564
IM 3564 AND CHILD WITH EXIT CODE 8 TERMINATED
CHILD | PID: 3574, PPID: 3564
IM 3564 AND CHILD WITH EXIT CODE 10 TERMINATED
```

which makes me wonder how fork really works and what code new processes really execute. Looking at the above output results, I can not understand:

1. How does *second for cycle* prints before *first for* finish all iterations? I've also noticed this *second for* is always executed by parent process, which makes me wonder if while on *first for cycle*, `if pid != 0` (which means parent process calling) *second for cycle* is executed (?)
2. Why does CHILD processes are not sorted printed by PID?

**So, bottom line, how does fork really works and who executes what?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you `fork`, the kernel creates a new process which is a copy of the forking process, and both processes continue executing after the `fork` (with the return code showing whether an error occurred, and whether the running code is the parent or the child). This “continue executing” part doesn’t necessarily happen straight away: the kernel just adds the new process to the run queue, and it will eventually be scheduled and run, but not necessarily immediately.

This explains both behaviours you’re asking about:

- since new processes aren’t necessarily scheduled immediately, the parent might continue running before any child gets a chance to run;
- creation order doesn’t have much (if any) impact in the run queue, so there’s no guarantee the child processes will run in the order they’re created.

Comment: I think I understand the not sorted prints, but to clarify: is the second for only executed by parent because child processes always reach return status because of _exit invocation?

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise you were asking about that too. Yes, the children exit as soon as they print their message, because of the call to `_exit`. So the second `for` loop is only run by the parent.

Comment: perfect! just to clarify two more aspects, if I may : 1) going deeper in your main answer: I've no guarantees that child processes will print by order, but I have guarantees that they are created by order, correct? (for example, if I create a int array[10] and in first for cycle I do pids[i] = fork() I can guarantee that array is sorted by child processes creation, right?); 2) I realize that if I remove `_exit()` call things go messy, with 1023 new processes created. Does this mean that if `_exit()` is not called, children processes aren't naturally terminated/killed for good?

Comment: (sorry for being abusive perhaps, but you are clearing out many things this moment)

Comment: Yes, the children are created in order, so if you store the pids you can wait for them in the right order. If you remove the `_exit` call, you will indeed have many more new processes created. Children just continue executing their code, in the same way as any process; so they’ll continue until they explicitly exit or they return from `main`.