# The file used by parent and child process

Tags: process, shared-file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int main( int argc, char *argv[] ){


    FILE *fptr;
    pid_t pid;

    fptr = fopen("Shared File.txt", "a");
    pid = fork();

    if( pid > 0 ){ // parent process

        int counter = 0;

        while( counter < 10 ){
            fprintf(fptr, "a");
            ++counter;
        }
        wait(NULL);
    }
    else{

        int counter = 0;

        while( counter < 5 ){
            fprintf(fptr, "b");
            ++counter;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I execute this code, the file produced by the code contains this message: bbbbbaaaaaaaaaa

Whenever I execute this code, I get same message. Why does not the processes write to file in shuffling order ?

Why does the operating system try to finish the child process at first ?

My expectation about the message is like this: baabbaaabaaabaa There is no continuous transition between the processes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The scheduling between parent and child has been discussed already (at least) in [When child processes are executed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/445109/170373) and [How does fork system call really works](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/350301/170373).

But in this case, there's also the question of buffering within `stdio`.
You're using `fprintf()` to write to a regular file. By default, `stdio` buffers output to regular files until enough data is written, to save on system call overhead. On x86 Linux, it usually seems to write in 4096 byte blocks, but you can't count on that, unless you set the buffering manually (see [`setbuf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3p.html) and friends).

You can see this with a command like `strace` that shows the system calls a program makes.

So, while you can't make any predictions about which process runs first, in this case you can predict that the `a`s are written consecutively, and the `b`s as well. You can only get `bbbbbaaaaaaaaaa` or `aaaaaaaaaabbbbb`, and which one you get is pretty much up to chance.

Answer (score 2):

I mostly agree with @ikkachu, except

Which one you get `bbbbbaaaaaaaaaa` or `aaaaaaaaaabbbbb` is predictable. The OS waits for child to finish, because of `wait(NULL)`, then the parent exits. As buffers are flushed on exit, the child gets to write first.

However do not rely on the buffers being predictable. Use explicit flush when needed.

Comment: I think I've seen some of GNU utilities, I think `find` in particular, that use `fflush()`  before continuing processing  next file or next argument. Definitely seems like the proper practice.

Answer (score 1):

User ilkkachu gave a good explanation how buffering affects the output. My answer describes what would happen if you eliminate the buffering, e.g. by replacing the `fprintf` calls with calls to `write`. In this case you would get strictly alternating `a`s and `b`s. This is because the call to `write` causes a reschedule: writing in one process blocks, giving the turn to the other process, and so on.

Let's imagine what would happen if the call to write would **not** block. Then we would have to consider timescales: you would get much longer runs of `a`s and `b`s than just one or two at a time, because modern processors are capable of executing billions of instructions per second, but the scheduling frequency is typically something between 100 Hz and 1000 Hz. A process would be able to execute up to tens of millions of instructions before it is preempted and the other process is scheduled to run. Even taking into account the system call overhead, this would give the process time to print very long strings of consecutive `a`s or `b`s.

Answer (score 1):

ikkachu and Johan did an great job of explaining why you observed the behaviour that you did, so I slightly rewrote your program so that each process flushes the stream and sleeps for a second (so each thread has a chance to interleave differently each time), so that you can see the interleaving effect more clearly.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void) {
  FILE *fptr = stdout;
  pid_t pid;
  int counter = 0;

  pid = fork();

  if(pid > 0) { // parent process
    while(counter++ < 10) {
      fprintf(fptr, "aa");
      fflush(fptr);
      sleep(1);
    }
    wait(NULL);
    puts("");
  } else {
    while(counter++ < 5) {
      fprintf(fptr, "bbbb");
      fflush(fptr);
      sleep(1);
    }
  }
}
```

If you run this several times, you'll get different results once in a while:

```
~ $ ./thread
aabbbbaabbbbaabbbbaabbbbaabbbbaaaaaaaaaa
~ $ ./thread
aabbbbaabbbbaabbbbaabbbbaabbbbaaaaaaaaaa
~ $ ./thread
aabbbbaabbbbaabbbbaabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaa
~ $ ./thread
aabbbbaabbbbaabbbbaabbbbaabbbbaaaaaaaaaa
```